# What is the `xxxxxx` value in AWS redis host name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

Looking at the [AWS documentation for connecting to a redis and replication group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.html), the host  is described to be of the format

```
cluster-name.xxxxxx.node-id.region-and-az.cache.amazonaws.com
```

- What is the `xxxxxx` value and how is it generated?
- Is it safe to hard code it?

Answer (score 0):

The `xxxxxx` refers to a unique customer identifier. It's safe to hard-code at the account level.